# website is going to 404 error page

Tags: php, wordpress

On this website I am building for wordpress, the footer.php file that I am editing I can't seem to fix one of the links.

```
<a href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/contact-us/" class="btn btn-black text-uppercase pull-right">Contact Our Office</a>
```

When i click on the link it goes to a 404 page, and yes a contact-us page is real.

Comment: where did it direct you?

Comment: first check your page source and see if there is a working link there by copying it and directly executing that url.. it should be like - http://www.yoursite.com/contact-us/, check if it works..

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```
<a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/contact-us/" class="btn btn-black text-uppercase pull-right">Contact Our Office</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to use.

```
<?php echo site_url(); ?>
```

You should be able to just use.

```
<a href="/contact-us/" class="btn btn-black text-uppercase pull-right">Contact Our Office</a>
```